# How to create a usable KeyReleased method in java

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

I'm new to swing and I am trying to make the square move but only when the key is released (ex W) but when i hold down the key the square just moves

KeyListener Class

I want to make sure that a key was pressed and if it is still pressed it should return false but true if it was pressed then released
    package javaGD.GameAssistant.Input;

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

public class KeyManager implements KeyListener {
private boolean[] keys;

public KeyManager() {
    keys = new boolean[256];

}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    keys[e.getKeyCode()] = true;

}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    keys[e.getKeyCode()] = false;

}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

}

public boolean KeyPressed(int keycode) {
    return keys[keycode];

}

public boolean KeyReleased(int keycode) {
   return keys[keycode];
 }
}
```

Class where the square should move. 
KeyListener is inherited from GameAssistant(JFrame is created with the KeyListener)

```
package TestCode;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javaGD.GameAssistant.GameAssistant;

public class Game extends GameAssistant {
public int x, xSpeed, y, ySpeed;

public Game(String title, int width, int height, boolean makeResizable) {
    super(title, width, height, makeResizable);

}

@Override
public void setup() {
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
    xSpeed = 5;
    ySpeed = 5;
}

@Override
public void update() {
    if (this.Keyboard().KeyReleased(KeyEvent.VK_D)) {
        x += xSpeed;
    }

    if (this.Keyboard().KeyReleased(KeyEvent.VK_A)) {
        x -= xSpeed;
    }

    if (this.Keyboard().KeyReleased(KeyEvent.VK_W)) {
        y -= ySpeed;
    }

    if (this.Keyboard().KeyReleased(KeyEvent.VK_S)) {
        y += ySpeed;
    }
}

@Override
public void draw(Graphics g) {

    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.fillRect(x, y, 20, 20);

}
```

}

Comment: It is my understanding that if you hold a key down for a while and then release the key then on Windows you will get events like "pressed, pressed, pressed... released". On a Mac you get "pressed, released, pressed, released, pressed, released ...". This is why listening for events to move a player you generally listen for the "pressed" event.

Answer (score 1):

`KeyReleased` should be returning `!keys[keycode]`  Otherwise it will return `false` when released and `true` when pressed

```
public boolean KeyReleased(int keycode) {
   return !keys[keycode];
}
```

I would also recommend using the [Key bindings API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) over `KeyListener` as it's more reliable and re-usable.

If you are only planning on a limited number of input operations, I would use `Set` and a `enum`, this way you can decouple the "how" from the "what".

You `update` method doesn't care "how" the inputs are managed, only the "what is the state"

Conceptually, maybe something like...

```
public enum GameInput {
    UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT;
}

public class KeyManager implements KeyListener {

    private Set<GameInput> inputs = new HashSet<>();

    public KeyManager() {
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        // Check the key code, verify if it's one of the configured
        // actions keys
        // The key code could come from a configuration file which might
        // be customisable by the user...
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
            inputs.add(GameInput.UP);
        } else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
            // etc...
        } // etc...
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
            inputs.remove(GameInput.UP);
        } else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
            // etc...
        } // etc...
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

    }

    public boolean isKeyPressed(GameInput input) {
        return inputs.contains(input);

    }

    public boolean isKeyReleased(GameInput input) {
        return !isKeyPressed(input);
    }
}
```

And your `update` method might look like...

```
@Override
public void update() {
    if (this.Keyboard().isKeyReleased(GameInput.RIGHT)) {
        x += xSpeed;
    }

    if (this.Keyboard().isKeyReleased(GameInput.LEFT)) {
        x -= xSpeed;
    }

    if (this.Keyboard().isKeyReleased(GameInput.UP)) {
        y -= ySpeed;
    }

    if (this.Keyboard().isKeyReleased(GameInput.DOWN)) {
        y += ySpeed;
    }
}
```

Now your `update` method doesn't care "how" the inputs are generated, only what to do when they are (or aren't) set.

Personally, I'd use a `InputManager` class and further decouple it, so inputs could be generate via other means, like buttons, mouse inputs, game pads, etc...

## Runnable example...

Conceptually, this should work.  I say "conceptually", because while I was testing I came across a number of "weird" issues that I can't contribute to either Java (1.8) or MacOS - or because they are a combination of both...more details below...

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private Box box = new Box();

        public TestPane() {
            InputMap im = getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
            ActionMap am = getActionMap();

            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_W, 0, false), "Up.pressed");
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_W, 0, true), "Up.released");
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_S, 0, false), "Down.pressed");
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_S, 0, true), "Down.released");
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A, 0, false), "Left.pressed");
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A, 0, true), "Left.released");
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_D, 0, false), "Right.pressed");
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_D, 0, true), "Right.released");

            am.put("Up.pressed", new KeyAction(InputAction.UP, true));
            am.put("Up.released", new KeyAction(InputAction.UP, false));
            am.put("Down.pressed", new KeyAction(InputAction.DOWN, true));
            am.put("Down.released", new KeyAction(InputAction.DOWN, false));
            am.put("Left.pressed", new KeyAction(InputAction.LEFT, true));
            am.put("Left.released", new KeyAction(InputAction.LEFT, false));
            am.put("Right.pressed", new KeyAction(InputAction.RIGHT, true));
            am.put("Right.released", new KeyAction(InputAction.RIGHT, false));

            Timer timer = new Timer(5, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    box.update(getBounds());
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            timer.start();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(400, 400);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            box.draw(g);
        }

    }

    public class Box {

        public int x, xSpeed, y, ySpeed, width, height;

        public Box() {
            x = 0;
            y = 0;
            xSpeed = 1;
            ySpeed = 1;
            width = 10;
            height = 10;
        }

        public void update(Rectangle bounds) {
            if (!InputManager.INSTANCE.isSet(InputAction.LEFT)) {
                x -= xSpeed;
            }
            if (!InputManager.INSTANCE.isSet(InputAction.RIGHT)) {
                x += xSpeed;
            }
            if (InputManager.INSTANCE.isSet(InputAction.UP) && InputManager.INSTANCE.isSet(InputAction.DOWN)) {
                //
            } else if (!InputManager.INSTANCE.isSet(InputAction.UP)) {
                y -= ySpeed;
            } else if (!InputManager.INSTANCE.isSet(InputAction.DOWN)) {
                y += ySpeed;
            }

            if (x < bounds.x) {
                x = 0;
            } else if (x + width > (bounds.x + bounds.width)) {
                x = bounds.x + (bounds.width - width);
            }
            if (y < bounds.y) {
                y = 0;
            } else if (y + height > (bounds.y + bounds.height)) {
                y = bounds.y + (bounds.height - height);
            }
        }

        public void draw(Graphics g) {
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
        }
    }

    public enum InputAction {
        UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT;
    }

    public enum InputManager {
        INSTANCE;

        private Set<InputAction> actions = new HashSet<>();

        public void set(InputAction action) {
            actions.add(action);
        }

        public void remove(InputAction action) {
            actions.remove(action);
        }

        public boolean isSet(InputAction action) {
            return actions.contains(action);
        }
    }

    public class KeyAction extends AbstractAction {

        private InputAction action;
        private boolean apply;

        public KeyAction(InputAction action, boolean apply) {
            this.action = action;
            this.apply = apply;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("!");
            if (apply) {
                System.out.println("Apply " + action);
                InputManager.INSTANCE.set(action);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Remove " + action);
                InputManager.INSTANCE.remove(action);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## TL;DR

While testing the above example, I came across a bizarre number of issues, I've not seen before (not that I've been doing this kind of thing recently).

When using `KeyListener`, if I pressed (and held) two buttons, I could see the "pressed" action, but there was no repeating events, which is something I would normally expect (for any keys).  When I released on key, I saw the "release" action, but when I pressed (and held it), no new "press" action was generated.

I tried the key bindings API (as demonstrated above) and still had no success (similar results).

I then attached a `AWTEventListener` directly to the event queue and monitored ALL the key strokes.

I noted that, some times (even is just tapping a key repeatedly) that "pressed" might not be generated.

I also noted that holding one or more keys down, releasing and pressing a key again, more often then not, did not generate a new press event (only release events)

I'm using macOS 10.13.6 and Java 1.8.0_144-b01 - it could be bug in either or both, but I don't have the means to test it otherwise

## Update...

So, after updating from Java 1.8 to Java 1.10, the above mentioned issue seems to be resoled - however, this highlights another, hardware issue, where only a certain number of keys can be actively pressed at a time - See [How do I remove the limit on PC keyboard button presses?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6669/how-do-i-remove-the-limit-on-pc-keyboard-button-presses) for more details

Comment: I've tried that and it acts like the KeyPressed method

Comment: While I'm scratching my head over this, what's the "default" state - you can't move left and right at the same time...

Comment: Okay, it's taken me a little bit of time to put something together, BUT, `KeyListener` doesn't like having a key pressed and then trying to respond to new release/press events from different keys :/

Comment: I've been able to accomplish your goal due to the fact that the API just doesn't seem to support it (at least on the Mac).  When I hold two keys down and release one, I'm unable to generate new key press events for other keys until I release the other key

Comment: Okay, after a bit more debugging - I seem to have discovered a bug, either in macOS or Java or both.  When holding a key down, `KeyListener` (and the key bindings API and `AWTEventListener`) should generate repeated key events - but in my testing they are not.  It's also not generating key press events when it should, but, always generates key release key events.  Your milage may fair better

Comment: I'm on windows 10 and it does generate a keypressed event even when holding it I think its macOS

Comment: it's okay I'll figure it out eventually 

Comment: Soooo... apparently updating from Java 1.8 to Java 1.10 fixes the issue 